# Is there a fast way to loop around a 2d array's boarder/edge?

Tags: loops, multidimensional-array

As indicated by the question. I'm doing an assignment where the boarder is defined to be some number while the inner 2d array need some calculation. I wrote:

```
 for(int col = 0; col < this.w; col++){
    energyMatrix[0][col]  = 195075;
    energyMatrix[this.h-1][col] = 195075;
 }
 for(int row = 1; row < this.h - 1; row++){
    energyMatrix[row][0] =  195075;
    energyMatrix[row][this.w-1] = 195075;
 }
```

but is there another (faster) way to do this?

Comment: No - that's fine, and this part of the code is probably not a bottleneck anyway - it will typically be the interior processing that needs optimising, if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *may* be a number of different ways to achieve the same thing, if you'd just tell us which language you're actually coding it in :-) What you have is valid for (at a minimum) C, C++ and Java.

However, it's unlikely any of them will be much *faster* than what you have there. It's more likely that you'll get better performance improvements if you think more on a *macro* level (things like algorithm selection, caching and so on) rather than at this level of detail.

---

One thing you *could* try, although I still maintain it'll be of dubious improvement, would be to minimise the size of the second loop by doing more work in the first:

```
if (this.h >= this.w) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.w; i++) {
        energyMatrix[0][i]  = 195075;
        energyMatrix[this.h-1][i] = 195075;
        energyMatrix[i][0] =  195075;
        energyMatrix[i][this.w-1] = 195075;
    }
    for (int i = this.w + 1; i < this.h; i++) {
        energyMatrix[i][0] =  195075;
        energyMatrix[i][this.w-1] = 195075;
    }
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.h; i++) {
        energyMatrix[i][0] =  195075;
        energyMatrix[i][this.w-1] = 195075;
        energyMatrix[0][i]  = 195075;
        energyMatrix[this.h-1][i] = 195075;
    }
    for (int i = this.h + 1; i < this.w; i++) {
        energyMatrix[0][i]  = 195075;
        energyMatrix[this.h-1][i] = 195075;
    }
}
```

This may remove some of the code overhead in running loops but, as I stated, I don't think you'll get the performance improvement out of this that you expect.

And, as with all optimisation attempts, you should *measure, not guess!* Try it with real data and, if the benefit doesn't outweigh the cost (of the more complicated code), ditch it.